# Is there a term for "not portrait" photos?

Tags: terminology

My photos rarely have people (faces) in them. Is there a term for such photography?

Comment: Landscape? Wildlife? Architecture? Abstract? Depends almost entirely on what you *are* taking photos of.

Comment: I'm looking for a single word for "everything except portraits".

Comment: There isn't a word for photographs that don't have rocks in them, or anything green, or fluffy kittens either.

Comment: Peopleless photography.

Comment: non-Portraiture?

Comment: Without seeing your images, it's hard to tell, but "nobody" and "no recognizable people" are terms that come to mind. Another useful piece of information is who will be reading this term about your photographs. If it's for you when you search your images, then anything will do so long as you understand it. If it's for a particular buying group, they will have such terms and you need to find out what they use.

Comment: "Still life" is a specific thing, and really not close

Comment: I guess from godzilla perspective, urban landscape is still life.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no term for photos that don't involve people.  Photos are categorized based on what they are *of*, not what they are *not of*.  A photo is *not of* an infinite number of things.

If I take a photo of my wife indoors, it is not of outside, it is not of cats, it is not of nighttime, it is not of waterfalls, it is not of ants, it is not of the future, it is not of a TV, it is not of stars...

Having a term for what photos are not of simply doesn't make sense.

Comment: Would love to see your photos that *are* of the future. :-)

Comment: I might have a picture of a delorean somewhere...

Comment: @AJHenderson I do actually :) I saw one about 3 weeks ago...or was it tomorrow?

Comment: Let's invent a term.  How about aportraiture?  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Portraits are usually posed photographs, however if you are taking photos of people that are not posed in a traditional portrait fashion then you would refer to them as 'candid'.

You would typically call other photography types that do not involve people, something more appropriate.

Comment: I would never use "candid", even loosely, to refer to a photograph without people. *photography : showing people acting in a natural way because they do not know that they are being photographed* http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/candid

Comment: @coneslayer Did I say without people? I said 'could' and 'other', there was nothing specific about that and I also mentioned that you would likely use something more suitable.

Comment: Then state clearly what "other areas" of photography you would describe as "candid". Because right now it sounds like you mean areas other than portraiture or unposed photographs of people.

Comment: OK fine, I have updated the statement.

Answer (score -4):

From my knowledge, Portrait and Landscape are definitions of picture sizes. Usually portraits are "tall" photos" while Landscape are rotated 90º.

Its definately not about subject since you don't need people to take a portrait or a landscape photo.

Comment: Words can have multiple meanings. While "portrait" and "landscape" can refer to the orientation of a photograph, they also refer to subject matter. (Not coincidentally, portraits are most often photographed in portrait orientation, and landscapes are most often photographed in landscape orientation.)

Comment: *portrait: a painting, drawing, or photograph of a person that usually only includes the person's head and shoulders* http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/portrait

Comment: *landscape: a picture that shows a natural scene of land or the countryside* http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/landscape

Comment: portrait and landscapes are definitions of paper orientations, not picture sizes. a portrait of a person, or crowd of people, can often be in landscape orientation. Likewise, a landscape scene looking out across the hills can be taller than it is wide. As a side, what happens if the image composition consists of only sea and is wider than tall? maybe it's a landscape seascape :)